# text-overflow ellipsis on table cell does not work in IE8 and IE9

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

This code works in every browser just fine, of course except IE8 and IE9. Unfortunately those specific users are not allowed to use any other browsers in their environment. Googled for 3 hours, tried all possible CSS solutions, but it wont work. Please advice.

`table-layout: fixed` is not going to work, because table cells need to have specific width.

http://jsfiddle.net/s7va8mLc/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/s7va8mLc/1/embedded/result/ (for IE8 view)

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Test</th>
        <td>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}

th {
    width: 250px;
}

td {
    width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

IE8-9 result:

[image: IE8-9 result]

Comment: “Don’t work” is not a problem description; tell us what happens. And explain “`table-layout: fixed` is not going to work, because table cells need to have specific width"; fixed table layout *means* that cells have specific widths instead of expanding according to content.

Comment: Just an idea, but you could try putting a div with a width of 250px in the first cell.

Comment: [`-ms-text-overflow` maybe](http://mattsnider.com/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/)?  Perhaps a [jQuery](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) option?  Or a [pure Javascript](http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2007/08/ellipsis-or-truncate-with-dots-via-javascript) option?

Comment: Agree with @JukkaK.Korpela not sure I understand why `table-layout: fixed;` can't be used as it would produce the result you are after.

Comment: I tested your fiddles in IE with emulation for IE8 and IE9 and they look exactly like you want them to look.

Comment: @Danield I found that too but I was able to see the issue in an actual version of IE8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, hope it helps (tested in IE8 natively).

http://jsfiddle.net/s7va8mLc/7/

http://jsfiddle.net/s7va8mLc/7/embedded/result/

HTML

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <th>Test</th>
    <td>
        <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </span>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
th {
    width: 250px;
}
td, span {
    width: 250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
span {
    display: block;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't use any tags inside of `<td>`

Comment: Why can't you? I'm afraid this is only way how to do that.

Comment: Accepting this just to get more points. It's not the solution I implemented.

Comment: So whats is the solution you implemented?

Answer (score 2):

For getting internet explorer's compatibility you need type  tag at the top like that :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Now run this again, I hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: This got nothing to do with my question.

Comment: I had checked your code in my internet explorer 8 and it's working fine after this tag at the top.

Comment: Fixing a doctype can often resolve issues like this, you shouldn't be so hasty.

Answer (score 2):

In your td put a tag like p, span, label and fix its width some less than div width.
Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

just use `td width property` to `50%` instead of  tag it will work on all the browsers i believe.

**[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7va8mLc/9/)**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td  class="text-center" width="50%">Test</td>      
        <td width="50%">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

.text-center{  
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```